# Would it be possible for me to use a Bluetooth chip I got for my Arduino with an ASUS ROG motherboard?

Tags: wireless-networking, motherboard, bluetooth, dsd

I recently made my own PC and the motherboard does not have built in Bluetooth or Wi-Fi.

I have a dongle for the Wi-Fi but nothing yet for the Bluetooth.

However, I have a Bluetooth chip that I bought for a project for my Arduino but never used. The chip in particular is [DSD Tech HM-19](http://www.dsdtech-global.com/2018/06/dsdtech-hm-19.html). My motherboard is [ASUS ROG STRIX B450-F](https://rog.asus.com/uk/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-b450-f-gaming-model/spec/).

Am I able to use this chip with my motherboard to gain bluetooth?

Comment: Highly doubtful this could be done. On a most basic physical level, the Bluetooth chip for the Arduino would need to be soldered to the ASUS ROG motherboard. On a logical level, how would that even work? You are much better off just buying a USB Bluetooth dongle or get an expansion card that can do Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.

Comment: Since the bluetooth is just basic serial based, you would need to go and purchase a serial pcie card and connect it up, but why bother since a cheap bluetooth dongle would probably be cheaper.

Comment: That bluetooth chip does not support USB so at best you would need some kind of serial port you could connect to it. It probably also does not work at the same voltage levels as a "standard" serial port so you would need some level-shifting electronics as well. The datasheet for the chip also says it only works up to 8KBytes/s so you would never be able to use it to connect a headset or do anything particularly useful. At best you could probably connect a bluetooth keyboard but it would be more work than it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

Your motherboard doesn't have Bluetooth, and you can't just
easily stick a chip to an existing motherboard.

But there are simple ways to add this feature to your PC :

1. **Bluetooth USB Adapter**

USB Bluetooth adapters are relatively cheap and easy to buy.
They offer the same usability as a built-in Bluetooth module would.

You can find standalone Bluetooth USB adapter that are not coupled
with WiFi.

2. **Using a Bluetooth PCIe Card**

A more robust built-in solution is a PCIe card.
Such cards tend to be faster and more reliable than USB adapters and
also tend to feature a newer version of Bluetooth.

You will need a free PCIe slot in your PC.
Additionally, a Bluetooth PCIe card almost always comes with WiFi.

Comment: Is there a substantial difference, other than the price, between a Bluetooth 2.0 USB adapter and any later version that a user should be aware of that could influence their choice of device to purchase?

Comment: @AndrewMorton: The only consideration would be that the USB adapter should be fast enough to support the speed of the Bluetooth connection. USB 2.0 has 480 Mbit/s maximum, which is quite enough for today's Bluetooth products.